# C# MVC 4 RAZOR - JSON return List from Controller to View using @foreach

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new in MVC 4 Razor as I am going deeper into it I am thinking that, is it possible to pass a JSON list in ActionResult to View?

Here is my code in Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    User _user = db.Users.ToList();
    return Json(_user , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my code in View: I want to place my JSON in `@foreach`

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC_AjaxActionLink.Models.User>
    <body>
        <input id="txtUser_Idx" type="text" />
        <input id="btnSend" name="btnSend" type="button" value="Search" />
        <div id="User_Result">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.User_Idx)
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LoginName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleInitial</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }
        </div>
    </body>
```

Here is my SQL table:

```
USE [Sample_db]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [User_Idx] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LoginName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MiddleInitial] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [User_Idx] ASC
))

GO
```

Comment: If you are returning JSON object you will need to use Jquery to process it and render it on view.

Comment: sir i tried this but it is difficult to format the design in here i use ajax

Comment: sir updated the post i put my ajax

Comment: Yes of course, but your method is returning a single `User`, not a collection so its difficult to understand what your really wanting to do.

Comment: And since `_user` is a collection, you cannot use code such as `User_Idx = _user.User_Idx,`. What are you actually wanting to do - return all the `User` objects returned by `db.Users.ToList()`?

Comment: yes sir i want to display all the List of User in my View

Comment: yes sir i just want to pass the List of User to @foreach (var item in Model)

Comment: like @foreach (var item in Json)

Comment: User _user = db.Users.ToList();  return Json(_user , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); >>like this

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code its hard to know where to start. But what is the point of your `<input id="txtUser_Idx" type="text" />` element - you send its value to the method but never use it. Are you really trying to return just the `User` that matches that `id`?

Comment: sir no i already accomplish to return a single user fronm txtUser_Idx, now i just want to display all the List of User from JSON to the View and use it in @foreach

Comment: and i dont know if it is possible to display JSON List like this >>                     @foreach (var item in Json)

Comment: Then why are you not passing a model to the view that includes all items. Sorry, but apart from all the errors in your code, your not making sense. Do you want to initially display all users, and then if you enter a value in the input, then display that item (in which case you don't need any ajax)?

Comment: public ActionResult Index() //Not This
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult Index() //But this
{
   return Json(db.Users.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

Comment: edited added a model into the View

Comment: @JohnLiz15. You still have not answered my questions!

Comment: i want to display all the Json List into the View sir but not a specific user

Comment: because i think JSON render more faster than @foreach (var item in Model)

Comment: Its not faster! Its just pointless to call a method that initially generates the main html but omits the html for the data so that you then need to make another call back to the server to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing two divergent technologies here.  Json over Ajax and Razor.  You can't bind a Json model object to a razor view.  It doesn't work that way.  If you want to use server side rendering with razor then you pass the model object to your view.

so

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    User _user = db.Users.ToList();
    return Json(_user , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

should be changed to this (assuming your razor view is Index.cshtml):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    User _user = db.Users.ToList();
    return View(_user);
}
```

and on a side note, I would recommend using _users in your controller not user because you're really returning a collection of users not a single user.